# How can I autofill dates in Excel excluding Sunday?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I autofill a list of sequential dates in Excel excluding Sunday? I want Monday April 8 to Saturday April 13, then back to Monday April 15.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a basic way to do it

Fill the dates for the first week in the first six rows (say `A2` to `A7`).

In the seventh row, insert the following formula:

```
=A2+7
```

And populate down

Another way is to insert the first day in `A2` then use the following formula

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2+1)=1,A2+2,A2+1)
```

and again, populate down

Comment: Yet another variant of the second: `=A2+1+(WEEKDAY(A2+1)=1)*1`

Comment: oooh! Clever use of the true/false numerical values, hadn't thought of that one

Comment: Yes, it also opens up for more complex series generation.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem can be solved by using below shown method also:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter start date, **04/08/2019** in Cell `A1` 
  (Cell Format is `mm/dd/yyyy`).
- Write this Formula in Cell `A2` & fill it down 
  till you need.

  `=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)<>6,A1+1,A1+2)`
- Enter this formula in Cell `C1` to 
  justify the Formula in `Column A`, and 
  fill it Down also.

  `=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A1,1),"DDDD")`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*